# Executing Excel Macro From ColdFusion Server

Tags: java, excel, coldfusion, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I have a ColdFusion Web application which lets the user upload an Excel Workbook on the server.

I would like to execute a macro within that Excel file, once the file has been uploaded.

Anyone has an idea on how I could manage to do that??

Note: I can use Java objects too, I am already using HSSF POI to access the Sheets' content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a way to do such thing:

1) Write a VBS Script file on the server like so:

```
    <cfset contentVBS = 
            "Dim objXL" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) &
            "Set objXL = CreateObject(" & Chr(34) & "Excel.Application" & Chr(34) & ")" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) &
            "With objXL" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) &
            "   .Workbooks.Open (" & Chr(34) & VARIABLES.Instance.filePath & VARIABLES.Instance.fileName & Chr(34) & ")" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) &
            "   .Application.Run " & Chr(34) & VARIABLES.Instance.macroName & Chr(34) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) &
            "   .Application.Quit" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) &
            "End With" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) &
            "Set objXL = Nothing" & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
    />

    <cffile
        action="write"
        charset="utf-8"
        file="#VARIABLES.Instance.filePath##VARIABLES.Instance.script_vbs_name#"
        output="#contentVBS#"
        addnewline="no"
    >
```

Where `VARIABLES.Instance.filePath` is the path to my Excel file, `VARIABLES.Instance.fileName` is the name of my Excel file and , `VARIABLES.Instance.macroName`is the name of the macro I want to launch.

2) Execute the vbs file using cscript.exe:

```
    <cfexecute name = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cscript.exe"
        arguments = "#VARIABLES.Instance.filePath##VARIABLES.Instance.script_vbs_name#">
    </cfexecute>
```

Where `VARIABLES.Instance.script_vbs_name` is the name of the VBS script file I just written.

Note: The macro generates a file on the server so I needed to specify to the ColdFusion Server read/write access to the folder.

Answer (score 2):

POI, and similar java libraries, cannot run macros. Running a macro requires the MS Excel application, which means it must be installed on the server. Then accessed via COM, Excel.Interop, etcetera.

That said, normally you do not want to execute macros on a server for security reasons. So my first question would be what does this macro do? If you can tell us what are you ultimately trying to achieve, maybe there is simpler and safer alternative.

Comment: I agree with Leigh - generally whatever task is being handled by the macro will be better served rewritten in a server side language anyway (faster, more scalable etc). (I just follow Leigh around and applaud all her (or his) comments... good for my reputation :)

Comment: Haha, I do not think your reputation needs boosting ;)

Comment: I'm trying to decide if that was a dig or a compliment. Being an optimist I'll take it as the latter :)

Comment: The macro is different according to the excel file (VBA code differs). The macro generates sql scripts on the server which are executed on the fly...

Comment: @MarkAKruger - Oh no, definitely a compliment :)

Comment: @FrancisP - Hm.. it still sounds like something better handled by a server side script. Plus user macros accessing databases sounds a bit dangerous to me :)

Comment: @Leigh - It's an internal tool and a server side script couldn't handle all the excel macros. Plus we already have +100 different Excel files with different implementation the the same Macro...

Comment: @FrancisP - To clarify, the idea of using a server side script is to replace the macros. For example, in sql server you do similar things in an SSIS package. But you know your setup best. (Sorry, user supplied macros running on my server just makes me nervous ;-)

Comment: @Leigh - I know it's not the best solution but since all those files must have their Macros executed in the future, the company wants the macros to be executed this way. (Anyway I'm not taking many decisions as an intern...)

Comment: @FrancisP - Yeah, I got the impression you had certain restrictions that could not be altered. So I was not trying to convert you ;) Just clarify the options, both for you and anyone reading this thread in the future.